# How do I retrieve a product key from another hard drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, product-key

My friend's laptop motherboard died and he needs his Windows 7 product key from the hard drive (which is still working).

I connected the old drive as a secondary drive to my own computer and tried using a key finder utility, but it just keeps showing my own product key and not his.

Is there a way to retrieve the product key from the old drive using my computer?

Comment: Just use one of the many tools that can do this. See http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/ And FWIW, *My friend's laptop's motherboard fried and he needs his Windows 7 product key* Most laptops have a COA sticker with the product key on it. See it [here](http://www.365laptoprepair.com/ebay_images/3506_Toshiba-Satelite-A500-A505-Bottom-Case-V000190490-WIN7-COA_1.JPG) (upside down, and an actual product key...)

Answer (score 56):

It’s possible, but a little tricky. You need to extract the product key from the Windows registry hive files from the target drive.

There’s different ways to do it, but probably the quickest and easiest way is with Nirsoft’s [ProduKey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html):

1. Download, extract, and run the program (it will show your own key by default)
2. Press <kbd>F9</kbd> to bring up the *Select Source* dialog
3. Select *Load the product keys from external Software Registry hive*
4. Browse to the `SOFTWARE` registry hive. For example, if you have the drive from the other system mounted as drive `Z:`, then you would probably select `Z:\Windows\System32\Config\SOFTWARE`
5. Click `[OK]`

It should read the hive file from the other copy of Windows and display the appropriate product key.

In this screenshot, I ran ProduKey in Windows XP (installed in `C:`) and then extracted the key from Windows 7 (mounted as `T:`). Note how it still says `C:\Windows` since Windows 7 was indeed installed in `C:`, even though it’s files are currently accessible from `T:`.

[image: Screenshot of ProduKey with default Windows key displayed and external Windows key displayed]

Comment: when i try to to find window\config it isnt there in the os J:... could it be located in a different file? also his product key on the sticker has faded of course.

Comment: @DatQuestion, oops, it’s not `Windows\Config`, it’s `Windows\System32\Config`. Fixed; thanks.

Comment: ok thank you soo much i found the file once again thank you soo much kind sir/ma'am

Comment: No problem. So you got the key?

Comment: `works automatically takes a bit longer worked on hdd with corrupt software file must look at hidden backups`   @anonymous; using the option `Load the product keys of external windows installations from all disks currently plugged into your computer` is not recommended for the reason I explained before the screenshot: as of Windows Vista, drive letters are not static and always say `C:\` which can make it confusing which installation is which, particularly when you have more than one or two. It is better to manually choose the *specific* installation. (Plus like you said, it takes longer.)

Comment: It's shameful how few computer technicians even know this is possible.  For me, it has worked every time, even on non-booting computers (assuming the drive is readable).  This is a very nicely laid out answer.

Comment: beware  of anti-Malwares

Comment: Can someone provide the correct path for recovering an XP product key? Better yet, list the paths for all of the common Windows OS. Awesome answer, +1 :D

Comment: I had to download from elsewhere to avoid the adware. I also had to run the program as admin before it would read the file. But otherwise worked fine!

Comment: There is no adware if you use the portable version. Using *other* versions may provide malware. That said, this great SW still works today. Had to extract a Windows 8.1 key from a dying HD, and works great as long as the registry hive is intact.

Comment: Please excuse shouty caps but very important: YOU MUST RUN PRODUKEY AS ADMINISTRATOR

Comment: @shrimpwagon, huh? No you don't. Produkey should be able to access the relevant keys without running elevated. The keys it needs to read are accessible by non-admin accounts, only *modifying* them requires elevated privileges. Is there a specific configuration that you couldn't do without running it elevated? 

Comment: @Synetech Yes... you do. I just had to. Sorry, I'm not wrong. I think you missed the point of accessing an external drive.

Comment: @shrimpwagon, no, I didn't, I did this without elevation last time I needed to a decade ago. Maybe things have changed in the past decade; Windows 10 isn't exactly user-friendly. In which case, you should have specified you need elevation *for Windows 10+*.

Comment: @Synetech .... "a decade ago." I just had to do it like last week. Yes, I'd say things have changed since 10 years ago :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the UEFI-embedded key and write it down, you can do so quite simply.

Just open the Start menu, type `powershell`, and run the Powershell application that comes up:

[image]

Then, enter the following command and press Enter:

```
(Get-WmiObject -query 'select * from SoftwareLicensingService').OA3xOriginalProductKey
```

[image]

> You should be rewarded with your embedded license key.
>
> **Write it down and store it in a safe place!**

---

#### Reference:

- https://www.howtogeek.com/206329/how-to-find-your-lost-windows-or-office-product-keys/

Comment: Finally some command-line-fu. What about from external drive with OS windows folder from another computer? (Like its done in the answer below.)

Comment: Replace with `Get-CimInstance`. ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54495023/1147688))